# font awesome invalid property value error

Tags: css, font-awesome

I added the following style to the code below :

```
 style="display: inline-block; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; font-family: fontAwesome; content: "\f0c9";"
```

Code:

```
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">

                        <i style="display: inline-block; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; font-family: fontAwesome; content: "\f0c9";" class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Exit</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" id="sign_Out">

                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Exit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

The font-awesome  file is defined in the css style , Why does not the icon appear?

Error in Inspect google chrome :  "invalid property value" and on the content word , line is drawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should use the following to import font awesome

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

For more details about how to use icons check the following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_icons.asp

EDIT:
in 4.7 version a circle appear, however moving to 5.7 version made the circle disappear so you should be careful what version you using

Answer (score 0):

`"\f0c9"` is breaking the inline style declaration since it is already wrapped in double quotes. Using `'\f0c9'` should help.